# Magento 1.9.2.4 including and excluding tax not working

Tags: magento, settings, magento-1.9, tax

I have a problem with displaying tax in Magento. The prices in the catalog need to be displayed as with tax and without tax. Magento also gives warnings in this configuration. Here are my settings.

> **Default settings**
> **Tax Classes** Tax Class for Shipping: None Tax Class For Surcharge: None
>
> **Calculation Settings** Tax Calculation Method Based On: Total Tax Calculation Based On: Shipping Address Catalog Prices: Excluding Tax
> Shipping Prices: Excluding Tax Surcharge Prices: Excluding Tax Apply
> Customer Tax: Before discount Apply Discount On Prices: Excluding Tax
> Apply Tax On: Custom price if available Enable Cross Border Trade: Yes
>
> **Default Tax Destination Calculation** Default Country: US Default State: * Default Post Code: *
>
> **Price Display Settings** Display Product Prices In Catalog: Excluding Tax Display Shipping Prices: Excluding Tax
>
> **Shopping Cart Display Settings** Display Prices: Excluding Tax Display Subtotal: Excluding Tax Display Shipping Amount: Excluding Tax
> Display Surcharge Prices: Excluding Tax Include Tax In Grand Total: No
> Display Full Tax Summary: No Display Zero Tax Subtotal: No
>
> **Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings** Display Prices: Excluding Tax Display Subtotal: Excluding Tax Display Shipping Amount:
> Excluding Tax Display Surcharge Prices: Excluding Tax Include Tax In
> Grand Total: No Display Full Tax Summary: No Display Zero Tax
> Subtotal: No
>
> **Fixed Product Taxes** Enable FPT: No Display Prices In Product Lists: Including FTP only Display Prices On Product View Page:
> Including FTP only Display Prices In Sales Modules: Including FTP only
> Display Prices In Emails: Including FTP only Apply Discounts To FPT:
> No FPT Tax Configuration: Not Taxed Include FPT In Subtotal: No
>
> **Shipping Settings**
> **Origin** Country: US Region/State: California ZIP/Postal Code: 90034 City: Empty Street Address: Empty Street Address Line 2: Empty
>
> **Options** Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses: Yes Maximum Qty Allowed for Shipping to Multiple Addresses: 100 Default Shipping
> Method: [tablerate] Table Rate
>
> ---
>
> **Website Settings**
> **Tax Classes** Tax Class for Shipping: 8.0% Tax Class For Surcharge: 8.0%
>
> **Calculation Settings** Tax Calculation Method Based On: Total [default checked] Tax Calculation Based On: Shipping Address [default
> checked] Catalog Prices: Excluding Tax [default checked] Shipping
> Prices: Excluding Tax [default checked] Surcharge Prices: Excluding
> Tax [default checked] Apply Customer Tax: Before discount [default
> checked] Apply Discount On Prices: Excluding Tax [default checked]
> Apply Tax On: Custom price if available [default checked] Enable Cross
> Border Trade: Yes [default checked]
>
> **Default Tax Destination Calculation** Default Country: Switzerland Default State: * Default Post Code: *
>
> **Price Display Settings** Display Product Prices In Catalog: Including and Excluding Tax Display Shipping Prices: Including and
> Excluding Tax
>
> **Shopping Cart Display Settings** Display Prices: Including and Excluding Tax Display Subtotal: Excluding Tax Display Shipping Amount:
> Excluding Tax Display Surcharge Prices: Excluding Tax [default
> checked] Include Tax In Grand Total: No Display Full Tax Summary: No
> Display Zero Tax Subtotal: No
>
> **Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings** Display Prices: Including and Excluding Tax Display Subtotal: Excluding Tax Display
> Shipping Amount: Excluding Tax Display Surcharge Prices: Excluding Tax
> [default checked] Include Tax In Grand Total: No Display Full Tax
> Summary: No Display Zero Tax Subtotal: No
>
> **Fixed Product Taxes** Enable FPT: No [default checked] Display Prices In Product Lists: Including FTP only [default checked] Display
> Prices On Product View Page: Including FTP only [default checked]
> Display Prices In Sales Modules: Including FTP only [default checked]
> Display Prices In Emails: Including FTP only [default checked] Apply
> Discounts To FPT: No [default checked] FPT Tax Configuration: Not
> Taxed [default checked] Include FPT In Subtotal: No [default checked]
>
> **Shipping Settings**
> **Origin** Country: Switzerland Region/State: ****** ZIP/Postal Code: ****** City: ****** Street Address: Empty [default checked] Street Address Line 2: Empty [default checked]
>
> **Options** Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses: No Maximum Qty Allowed for Shipping to Multiple Addresses: 100 [default checked]
> Default Shipping Method: [tablerate] Table Rate [default checked]
>
> ---
>
> **Store view** Default Tax Destination Calculation Default Country: Switzerland [default checked] Default State: * [default checked]
> Default Post Code: * [default checked]
>
> **Price Display Settings** Display Product Prices In Catalog: Including and Excluding Tax [default checked] Display Shipping Prices:
> Including and Excluding Tax [default checked]
>
> **Shopping Cart Display Settings** Display Prices: Including and Excluding Tax [default checked] Display Subtotal: Excluding Tax
> [default checked] Display Shipping Amount: Excluding Tax [default
> checked] Display Surcharge Prices: Excluding Tax [default checked]
> Include Tax In Grand Total: No [default checked] Display Full Tax
> Summary: No [default checked] Display Zero Tax Subtotal: No [default
> checked]
>
> **Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings** Display Prices: Including and Excluding Tax [default checked] Display Subtotal:
> Excluding Tax [default checked] Display Shipping Amount: Excluding Tax
> [default checked] Display Surcharge Prices: Excluding Tax [default
> checked] Include Tax In Grand Total: No [default checked] Display Full
> Tax Summary: No [default checked] Display Zero Tax Subtotal: No
> [default checked]

Could someone point out where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a migration tool to transfer everything to a newer version. And although all the setting above are correct the Customer Tax Classes were not in place. Finally solved this. Here are the docs if anybody has a similar problem. http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-class-customer.html